# Trying to pass by value in Javascript multi-dim array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I'm building a web site that you can play othello on as a code sample.  I've got a multidimensional array as the behind-the-scenes gameboard, and then iterate through every 'td' in a table to match the value of the corresponding array member.  The problem i'm encountering is that iterating through the table. and using the iterators as essentially coordinates to my array doesn't work.  As the iterator increases in value, so too does the coordinates in each of my 'td's.  I'm stumped, and running on fumes.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
function gridArray() {
    // creates game board's array.  
    for (var i = 0; i < gameArray.length; i++) {
        gameArray[i] = new Array(8);
    }

    for (var row = 0; row < gameArray.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < gameArray[row].length; col++) {
            gameArray[row][col] = "green";
        }
    }
}

function drawGrid(){
    // writes table to HTML document
    var htmlString = "<table id='othelloGrid'><tr>";
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            htmlString += "<th>" + i + "</th>";
        }
        htmlString += "</tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            htmlString += "<tr>";
            xPos = j;
            for (var x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                yPos = x;
                // HERE!!!  I now realize javascript passes by reference, so      as this loop iterates, 
                // every single 'td' is getting 'onclick = 'changeClass(7, 7)''.
                // for my game grid to work, I need each td to have a unique xPos, yPos to
                // connect back to gameArray.
                htmlString += "<td onclick = 'changeClass(xPos, yPos)'></td>";
            }
            htmlString += "</tr>";
        }
    htmlString += "</table>";

    return htmlString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Variables are not expanded inside strings. So all your TDs have the literal attribute `onclick='changeClass(xPos, yPos)'` in them, not the values of these variables from the loop. So when you actually click on them, they all use the most recent values of those variables.

You need to use string concatenation to get the values. And there's no need for the global variables `xPos` and `yPos`, you can use the local `j` and `x` variables.

```
htmlString += "<td onclick = 'changeClass(" + j + ", " + x + ")'></td>";
```

Comment: I've seen that in some cases it helps to use xval / yval as TD parameters. So, when you get click on a cell, you can always query `$(this).attr('xval')` or `$(this).attr('yval')` which will return the position on the table (hence eliminating the need of the iteration).

Comment: @AlbertoAlexanderRodriguez That's how I would do it, although you shouldn't create custom attributes like that. Use `data-xval`

Comment: Oh god bless you.  I need sleep.

Comment: I usually add custom attributes to avoid unnecessary iterations. The more, the merrier.

Comment: Why do you use custom attributes instead of using the standard `data-XXX` attributes? E.g. `data-xval="123"`

Comment: Then in jQuery you can use `$(this).data("xval")`